# How to minimize the front matter?

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, front-matter

In all my documents which I write using pdfLaTeX in *Overleaf*, I use a definite of set of packages and `\newcommand` statements in the front matter. All of these are used for the purpose of page setup, font setup, header on pages, defining readymade colours, section formatting, defining new type of mathematical symbols etc.

Now, as I have to accomodate all those codes in every single document, so my `\begin{document}` typically starts from maybe line no. 130. Sadly, this long code can't even be minimized (Unlike any section or subsection which can be minimized by a single click).

I am seeking for something which can made the front matter of my LaTeX code very compact. So, instead of this :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
.
.
.
\newcommand\bnorm[1]{\big\lVert#1\big\rVert}

\begin{document}
```

I wish I could do something like this :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{Something which imports all my preferred setup}

\begin{document}
```

I have seen a few people using their own `.sty` or `.bib` files, but the codes they write inside them are too complex for me to understand. So I was wondering if there is any more-or-less simple way to do this, i.e. to make my page setup codes (front matter) very compact.

Thanks in advance for your time. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to explain what **minimize by a single click** means in this context. Unrelated: see the mathtools package for a more flexible way to define norms

Comment: Overleaf allows to minimize a complete section (or subsection or ```\begin{  }```) by clicking on a little arrow symbol just beside the line number where the ```\section{  }``` is written.

Comment: unrelated but `\newcommand\bnorm[1]{\big\lVert#1\big\rVert}` should be `\newcommand\bnorm[1]{\bigl\lVert#1\bigr\rVert}` you lose the open and close spacing if you use `\big`

Comment: Note that _minimize_ is propably not the proper form for this feature. In some editors it goes under the term _code folding_. It is not really a LaTeX issue, it might be better to ask the overleaf support, perhaps they can add it as a feature request it Overleaf cannot already fold the preamble.

Comment: In LaTeX you can put any code in a separate file and then put `\input{otherfile}` in your main file, which seems to do what you want. An advantage is that you can reuse that file in other projects as well. There is no special syntax or boilerplate or anything needed, just copy any lines that you want to the other file and they will be executed as if they are part of the main file.

Comment: @Marijn, this is working. This is precisely what I wanted. Thank you !